# mPDF Connection timeout if no output

Tags: php, timeout, mpdf

I've been working on a site where it takes a while to process the data in the background (using mpdf to generate multiple pdf pages).

It keeps running if I output the number of loop forexample, using ob_get_clean each time and so on.

However, if I wait for the file to be generated by the code and not use the ob_get_clean, no output comes, nor the process complete.

I did it like this:

Saved all the html from the loop in an array `$newhtml` and then:

```
foreach($newhtml as $htmlkey => $htmlvalue){

  if('0'==$htmlkey){
    echo '<p><b>Total Invoices: </b>' . count($newhtml) . '</p>
    <p><b>Generating:</b></p>';
  }
  echo $htmlkey. ', ';

  while(ob_get_level())ob_end_clean();// remove output buffers
  ob_implicit_flush(true); 
  set_time_limit(100);

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlvalue); 
    $mpdf->AddPage('','','','','',1,1,1,1,0,0); 
}

$mpdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

It takes the most time at $mpdf->WriteHTML (tested by commenting it out, then in next test leaving it there and commenting other ones out)

Want to know the reason and how to solve it without outputting something.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: if there is no error then your code should be fine unless a single iteration takes more than 100 seconds. Are you sure that error output is enabled and you dont get some buffer overflow or memory limit error?

Comment: no it stops in 30 seconds if ob_end_clean is commented